# Facebook Marketing API - Python to get Insights - User Request Limit Reached

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights, facebook-marketing-api

So I am trying my best to navigate my way through the Facebook API. I need to crate a script that will download my business' campaign information daily as a csv file so I can use another script to upload the information to our database easily.

I finally have code that works to print the information to the log, but I am reaching the user request limit because I have to call get_insights() for every single campaign individually. I am wondering if anyone knows how to help me make it so I don't have to call the facebook API as often.

What I would like to do if find a field where I can get the daily spend so I don't have to call the API in every iteration of my for campaign loop, but I cannot for the life of me find a way to do so.

```
#Import all the facebook mumbo jumbo
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.adset import AdSet
from facebookads.adobjects.campaign import Campaign
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adreportrun import AdReportRun
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.business import Business
import time

#Set the login info
my_app_id = '****'
my_app_secret = '****'
my_access_token = '****'

#Start the connection to the facebook API
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

business = Business('****')

#Get all ad accounts on the business account 
accounts = business.get_owned_ad_accounts(fields=[AdAccount.Field.id])

#iterate through all accounts in the business account
for account in accounts:
    tempaccount = AdAccount(account[AdAccount.Field.id])
    #get all campaigns in the adaccount
    campaigns = tempaccount.get_campaigns(fields=[Campaign.Field.name,Campaign.Field])
    #iterate trough all the campaigns in the adaccount
    for campaign in campaigns:
        print(campaign[Campaign.Field.name])
        #get the insight info (spend) from each campaign
        campaignsights = campaign.get_insights(params={'date_preset':'yesterday'},fields=[AdsInsights.Field.spend])
        print (campaignsights)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It took a while of digging through the API and guessing but I got it! Here is my final script:

```
# This program downloads all relevent Facebook traffic info as a csv file
# This program requires info from the Facebook Ads API: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk

# Import all the facebook mumbo jumbo
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.business import Business

# Import th csv writer and the date/time function
import datetime
import csv

# Set the info to get connected to the API. Do NOT share this info
my_app_id = '****'
my_app_secret = '****'
my_access_token = '****'

# Start the connection to the facebook API
FacebookAdsApi.init(my_app_id, my_app_secret, my_access_token)

# Create a business object for the business account
business = Business('****')

# Get yesterday's date for the filename, and the csv data
yesterdaybad = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
yesterdayslash = yesterdaybad.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
yesterdayhyphen = yesterdaybad.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

# Define the destination filename
filename = yesterdayhyphen + '_fb.csv'
filelocation = "/cron/downloads/"+ filename

# Get all ad accounts on the business account
accounts = business.get_owned_ad_accounts(fields=[AdAccount.Field.id])

# Open or create new file 
try:
    csvfile = open(filelocation , 'w+', 0777)
except:
    print ("Cannot open file.")


# To keep track of rows added to file
rows = 0

try:
    # Create file writer
    filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
except Exception as err:
    print(err)

# Iterate through the adaccounts
for account in accounts:
    # Create an addaccount object from the adaccount id to make it possible to get insights
    tempaccount = AdAccount(account[AdAccount.Field.id])

    # Grab insight info for all ads in the adaccount
    ads = tempaccount.get_insights(params={'date_preset':'yesterday',
                                           'level':'ad'
                                          },
                                   fields=[AdsInsights.Field.account_id,
                       AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.adset_id,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.cost_per_outbound_click,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.outbound_clicks,
                                           AdsInsights.Field.spend
                                          ]
    );

    # Iterate through all accounts in the business account
    for ad in ads:
        # Set default values in case the insight info is empty
        date = yesterdayslash
        accountid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.account_id]
        accountname = ""
        adid = ""
        adname = ""
        adsetid = ""
        adsetname = ""
        campaignid = ""
        campaignname = ""
        costperoutboundclick = ""
        outboundclicks = ""
        spend = ""

        # Set values from insight data
        if ('account_id' in ad) :
            accountid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.account_id]
        if ('account_name' in ad) :
            accountname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.account_name]
        if ('ad_id' in ad) :
            adid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.ad_id]
        if ('ad_name' in ad) :
            adname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.ad_name]
        if ('adset_id' in ad) :
            adsetid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.adset_id]
        if ('adset_name' in ad) :
            adsetname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.adset_name]
        if ('campaign_id' in ad) :
            campaignid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id]
        if ('campaign_name' in ad) :
            campaignname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name]
        if ('cost_per_outbound_click' in ad) : # This is stored strangely, takes a few steps to break through the layers
            costperoutboundclicklist = ad[AdsInsights.Field.cost_per_outbound_click]
            costperoutboundclickdict = costperoutboundclicklist[0]
            costperoutboundclick = costperoutboundclickdict.get('value')
        if ('outbound_clicks' in ad) : # This is stored strangely, takes a few steps to break through the layers
            outboundclickslist = ad[AdsInsights.Field.outbound_clicks]
            outboundclicksdict = outboundclickslist[0]
            outboundclicks = outboundclicksdict.get('value')
        if ('spend' in ad) :
            spend = ad[AdsInsights.Field.spend]

        # Write all ad info to the file, and increment the number of rows that will display
        filewriter.writerow([date, accountid, accountname, adid, adname, adsetid, adsetname, campaignid, campaignname, costperoutboundclick, outboundclicks, spend])
        rows += 1


csvfile.close()

# Print report
print (str(rows) + " rows added to the file " + filename)
```

I then have a php script that takes the csv file and uploads it to my database. The key is pulling all the insight data in one big yank. You can then break it up however you want because each ad has information about its adset, adaccount, and campaign.

Comment: You have no idea how much this post has helped me. Is not obvious how to access the data on the fields when you make the requests through the various SDKs. I keep coming back to this post because I haven't found any other source where this is clearly documented.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: What goes inside Business object instance, i.e '***'? My god facebook_business sdk is a nightmare... zero docstring

Comment: @MarcoFumagalli your business ID

Comment: Did someone please already have got the error below :

      Message: Call was not successful
      Method:  GET
      Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_**********/owned_ad_accounts
      Params:  {'fields': 'id', 'summary': 'true'}
    
      Status:  400
      Response:
        {
          "error": {
            "message": "(#2635) You are calling a deprecated version of the Ads API. Please update to the latest version: v8.0.",
            "type": "OAuthException",
            "code": 2635,
            "fbtrace_id": "***********"
          }
        }

Comment: @MohamedAzizi sounds like the API version you are using is outdated. Change you link from graph.facebook.com/v2.11/act_ ro graph.facebook.com/v8.0/act_

Comment: Does the 'get_insights' returns data for all the pages? No need to handle pagination in the result?

Answer (score 6):

Adding a couple of small functions to improve on LucyTurtle's answer as it is still susceptible to Facebook's Rate Limiting

```
import logging
import requests as rq

#Function to find the string between two strings or characters
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

#Function to check how close you are to the FB Rate Limit
def check_limit():
    def check_limit():
    check=rq.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.3/act_'+account_number+'/insights?access_token='+my_access_token)
    call=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'call_count":','}'))
    cpu=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'total_cputime":','}'))
    total=float(find_between(check.headers['x-business-use-case-usage'],'total_time":',','))
    usage=max(call,cpu,total)
    return usage

#Check if you reached 75% of the limit, if yes then back-off for 5 minutes (put this chunk in your 'for ad is ads' loop, every 100-200 iterations)
if (check_limit()>75):
    print('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    logging.debug('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    time.sleep(300)
```

Comment: I believe yoou wanted to write: 

`if (check_limit()>75):`

Comment: Yes, Thanks @helloworld

Comment: Anytime, check my post, I tagged you there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537459/11050796

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to say
Thank you.
As Marks Andre said - you made my day! 
The FB SDK documentation is exhaustive, but it completely lacks the practical implementation examples for day-to-day-tasks like this one. Bookmark is set - page will be revisited soon.

So the only thing I can actually contribute for fellow sufferers: it seems that with the newer facebook_business SDK you can simply completely replace "facebookads" in the import statements with "facebook_business".