# I can't fetch stats for all my facebook campaigns using Python and Facebook Marketing API

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I'm trying to retrieve the following metrics: `date, campaign_name, impressions, clicks & spend`,  of all the campaigns in my facebook account but apparently the script I wrote returns only stats for some campaigns and not all of them. It returns only the campaign_name and its id for most of the campaigns.

I'm having this doubt that it only returns the stats for active campaigns and not the inactive ones. Anyone knows how I can mention that I always want to fetch inactive/paused campaigns?

Here is the the script I'm using:

```
import requests
import json

token = 'MY TOKEN'
act_id = 'MY ACCOUNT ID'
first_request = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_id/campaigns?fields=created_time,name,insights{spend,impressions,clicks}&access_token=%s'%token
```

Then I run the following:

```
campaigns=[]
current_request = first_request
while True:
  result = requests.get(current_request)
  content_dict = json.loads(result.content)
  for x in content_dict['data']:
    campaigns.append(x)
  if 'next' in content_dict['paging']:
    m = content_dict['paging']['next'].find('&after')
    current_request = first_+content_dict['paging']['next'][m:]
    print('next request: ', current_request)
  else:
    break
```

A sample of the output (first campaigns with the desired stats, and second without) :

```
[{'created_time': '2019-03-29T12:00:29+0100',
  'id': '6133534332561',
  'insights': {'data': [{'clicks': '199',
     'date_start': '2019-03-03',
     'date_stop': '2019-04-01',
     'impressions': '35749',
     'spend': '71.44'}],
   'paging': {'cursors': {'after': 'MAZDZD', 'before': 'MAZDZD'}}},
  'name': '20190422-FB-BOOST-DSDS-CC JHISO- 2 - SDSDDE'},
{'created_time': '2019-01-31T16:06:01+0100',
  'id': '434465343233',
  'name': '20190204-FB-BOOST-SQ-CC FDSSZ- 3EEZK'}]
```

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834523/facebook-marketing-api-python-to-get-insights-user-request-limit-reached

Comment: Dear LucyTurtle, first thank you so much. Second, please refer to this post, I have  also taggerd you there when I posted an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55537459/11050796 . However, I exported a report from FB Ads Manager and I don't know why always numbers don't match (I'm getting less! )