# Not getting paused ads insights using Facebook Marketing API

Tags: python, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I wrote this script that returns a list of ads with their stats but apprently I'm getting only insights for active ads and not paused ones - For paused ones, I'm just getting the campaign name and its id !

I tried using filtering like below but it's not working:

''

```
first = "https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/act_105433210/campaigns?filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['PAUSED']}]&fields=created_time,name,effective_status,insights{spend,impressions,clicks}&access_token=%s"% token
```

Then I check using:

```
result = requests.get(first)
content_dict = json.loads(result.content)
print(content_dict)
```

and this is a sample of the output I get:

```
{'data': [{'created_time': '2019-02-15T17:24:29+0100', 'name': '20122301-FB-BOOST-EVENT-CC SDSDSD', 'effective_status': 'PAUSED', 'id': '6118169436761'}
```

There is only the name of the campaign and not insights ! 
Anyone did retrieve stats/insights for paused ads/campaigns before or not?

Thanks !

Please check my other post of my python script : [I can't fetch stats for all my facebook campaigns using Python and Facebook Marketing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469743/i-cant-fetch-stats-for-all-my-facebook-campaigns-using-python-and-facebook-mark)

Comment: after the `filtering` params use the `&` instead of `?` before `fields`

Comment: I tried with a valid adaccounts and work as expected for paused campaigns

Comment: possibly no insights exists for the campaign?

Comment: Lemme check if your theory is valid for some paused campaigns I got with insights

Comment: you can use multiple filtering params in order to combine your criteria (I can post an answer with an example if you need)

Comment: That would be great :) ! Thank you

Comment: see my updated answer

Comment: Dear Matteo, check the script I came up with after 3 days of diggin ! It did help me extract three years of ads insights all avoiding the rate limit of the FB API even if it's taking taking :) ! Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After days of digging around, I finally come up with a script that I did run to extract 3 years of facebook ads insights avoiding the rate limit of the facebook API.

First, we import the lib we'll need :

```
from facebookads.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebookads.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights
from facebookads.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebookads.adobjects.business import Business
import datetime
import csv
import re 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
from google.colab import files
import time
```

Please note that after extracting the insights, I'm saving them on Google Cloud storage then on Big Query tables.

```
access_token = 'my-token'
ad_account_id = 'act_id'
app_secret = 'app_s****'
app_id = 'app_id****'
FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id,app_secret, access_token=access_token, api_version='v3.2')
account = AdAccount(ad_account_id)
```

Then, the following scripts calls the api and check the rate limit we did reach:

```
import logging
import requests as rq

#Function to find the string between two strings or characters
def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""

#Function to check how close you are to the FB Rate Limit
def check_limit():
    check=rq.get('https://graph.facebook.com/v3.1/'+ad_account_id+'/insights?access_token='+access_token)
    usage=float(find_between(check.headers['x-ad-account-usage'],':','}'))
    return usage
```

Now, this is the whole script that you can run to extract data of the last X days !

```
Y = number of days 
for x in range(1, Y):

  date_0 = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=x )
  date_ = date_0.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
  date_compact = date_.replace('-', '')
  filename = 'fb_%s.csv'%date_compact
  filelocation = "./"+ filename
    # Open or create new file 
  try:
      csvfile = open(filelocation , 'w+', 777)
  except:
      print ("Cannot open file.")


  # To keep track of rows added to file
  rows = 0

  try:
      # Create file writer
      filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
      filewriter.writerow(['date','ad_name', 'adset_id', 'adset_name', 'campaign_id', 'campaign_name', 'clicks', 'impressions', 'spend'])
  except Exception as err:
      print(err)
  # Iterate through all accounts in the business account

  ads = account.get_insights(params={'time_range': {'since':date_, 'until':date_}, 'level':'ad' }, fields=[AdsInsights.Field.ad_name, AdsInsights.Field.adset_id, AdsInsights.Field.adset_name, AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id, AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name, AdsInsights.Field.clicks, AdsInsights.Field.impressions, AdsInsights.Field.spend ])
  for ad in ads:

    # Set default values in case the insight info is empty
    date = date_
    adsetid = ""
    adname = ""
    adsetname = ""
    campaignid = ""
    campaignname = ""
    clicks = ""
    impressions = ""
    spend = ""

    # Set values from insight data
    if ('adset_id' in ad) :
        adsetid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.adset_id]
    if ('ad_name' in ad) :
        adname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.ad_name]
    if ('adset_name' in ad) :
        adsetname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.adset_name]
    if ('campaign_id' in ad) :
        campaignid = ad[AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id]
    if ('campaign_name' in ad) :
        campaignname = ad[AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name]
    if ('clicks' in ad) : # This is stored strangely, takes a few steps to break through the layers
        clicks = ad[AdsInsights.Field.clicks]
    if ('impressions' in ad) : # This is stored strangely, takes a few steps to break through the layers
        impressions = ad[AdsInsights.Field.impressions]
    if ('spend' in ad) :
        spend = ad[AdsInsights.Field.spend]

    # Write all ad info to the file, and increment the number of rows that will display
    filewriter.writerow([date_, adname, adsetid, adsetname, campaignid, campaignname, clicks, impressions, spend])
    rows += 1

  csvfile.close()

# Print report
  print (str(rows) + " rows added to the file " + filename)
  print(check_limit(), 'reached of rate limit')
## write to GCS and BQ
  blob = bucket.blob('fb_2/fb_%s.csv'%date_compact)
  blob.upload_from_filename(filelocation)
  load_job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
  table_name = '0_fb_ad_stats_%s' % date_compact
  load_job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
  load_job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1

  # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
  load_job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV
  load_job_config.field_delimiter = ','
  load_job_config.autodetect = True
  uri = 'gs://my-project/fb_2/fb_%s.csv'%date_compact
  load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri,
    dataset.table(table_name),
    job_config=load_job_config)  # API request
  print('Starting job {}'.format(load_job.job_id))
  load_job.result()  # Waits for table load to complete.
  print('Job finished.')

  if (check_limit()>=75):
    print('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time 5 Minutes.')
    logging.debug('75% Rate Limit Reached. Cooling Time Around 3 Minutes And Half.')
    time.sleep(225)
```

This did perfectly works but note that if you're planning to extract 3 years of data, the script will take a lot of time to run !

I'd like to thank [LucyTurtle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6427750/lucyturtle) and [Ashish Baid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4218613/ashish-baid) for their scripts that did help me during my work!

Please refer to this post if you need more details or if you need to extract data for one day for different ad accounts :

> [Facebook Marketing API - Python to get Insights - User Request Limit Reached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834523/facebook-marketing-api-python-to-get-insights-user-request-limit-reached)

Comment: is this URL still working? I'm having trouble implementing this function. Also, how long did it take you to get all records and how many ads? Right now with a default sleep(250) between 50 calls which gets my limit at 80% takes more than 2 hours to get 2.5K ads.

Answer (score 1):

You could combine more filtering criteria as example, for filter paused campaign, that the name contain the string `name` and start from the 1 march you can use:

```
act_105433210/campaigns?filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['PAUSED']},{'field':'name','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'name'},{'field':'created_time','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'1551444673'}]&fields=created_time,name,effective_status,insights{spend,impressions,clicks}
```

the timestamp should be an epoch timestamp, in the example is the:

> Epoch timestamp: 1551444673 
>   Human time (GMT): Friday, March 1, 2019
>   12:51:13 PM

Comment: Dear Matteo, thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Please check my post! I updated my questions !

Comment: Crystal clear dear Matteo! Now i'll check if your theory is valid for a compaign and that know and keep you updated!

Comment: `campaigns?filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['PAUSED']},{'field':'name','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'Bay'},{'field':'created_time','operator':'LESS_THAN','value':'1543190400'}{'field':'created_time','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'1543017600'}]&fields=created_time,name,effective_status,insights{spend,impressions,clicks}&access_token=%s"% token`


I tried using this and I'm getting an error that says : `b'{"error":{"message":"(#100) param filtering must be an array.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"DDDDD"}}'`

Comment: You miss a comma, try this: `campaigns?filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['PAUSED']},{'field':'name','operator':'CONTAIN','value':'Bay'},{'field':'created_time','operator':'LESS_THAN','value':'1543190400'},{'field':'created_time','operator':'GREATER_THAN','value':'1543017600'}]&fields=created_time,name,effective_status,insights{spend,impressions,clicks}`

Comment: It returns nothing: `b'{"data":[]}'`

Comment: You are looking for old data, if I check data for paused campaign older than one year I can't retrieve any insights. I don't know if check insight older than one year could be a problem.

Comment: In fact I'm tyring to retrieve data from 2016 until today using the following script mentionned in my other post [I can't fetch stats for all my facebook campaigns using Python and Facebook Marketing API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55469743/i-cant-fetch-stats-for-all-my-facebook-campaigns-using-python-and-facebook-mark) !