# How can I get more than 25 results from Facebook's insights api using Facebook-business-python-sdk?

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-insights, facebook-python-business-sdk

I'm trying to get basic ad level data from Facebook's insights API using [facebook-python-business-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk) with python 3.7.
The problem is I'm only getting 25 results back, even in accounts that have more than 25 active ads.

I'm using the get_insights method on each account, passing a 'level':'ad' param and filtering on a specific date.
I've also checked whether I've reached facebook's limit (using the explanation provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47834523/facebook-marketing-api-python-to-get-insights-user-request-limit-reached))) and I'm not even close to the limit. 
The get_insights method doesn't have a 'limit' param and either way I don't want to limit it at all as some accounts may have hundreds or even thousands of ads.

This is the code I'm using

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccountuser import AdAccountUser
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign as AdCampaign
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights

access_token = '******'
app_secret = '******'
app_id = '******'

FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)

me = AdAccountUser(fbid='me')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())

params={'time_range': {'since': '2019-06-29', 'until': '2019-06-29'},'level': 'ad'}
fields = [AdsInsights.Field.account_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.adset_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.spend,
           AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
           AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
           AdsInsights.Field.outbound_clicks,
        ]

for account in my_accounts:
    ads = account.get_insights(params=params, fields=fields)
    print(ads)
    print(len(ads))
```

I expected to get all ads in each account but I'm only getting a maximum of 25 ads per account. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: have you tried adding the limit params like limit=9999?

Comment: otherwise you should follow the pagination element returned by the endpoint

Comment: which one? the limit field?

Comment: yes. The limit field.
It doesn't appear in the get_insights method as an available param. but it still worked

Comment: cool, do you prefer I post the comment as answer so you can close your question?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is just to add a 'limit' param, see below:

```
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccount import AdAccount
from facebook_business.adobjects.adaccountuser import AdAccountUser
from facebook_business.adobjects.campaign import Campaign as AdCampaign
from facebook_business.adobjects.adsinsights import AdsInsights

access_token = '******'
app_secret = '******'
app_id = '******'

FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, access_token)

me = AdAccountUser(fbid='me')
my_accounts = list(me.get_ad_accounts())

params={'time_range': {'since': '2019-06-29', 'until': '2019-06-29'},'level': 'ad', 'limit': '20000'}
fields = [AdsInsights.Field.account_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.account_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.ad_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.ad_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.adset_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.adset_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_id,
           AdsInsights.Field.campaign_name,
           AdsInsights.Field.spend,
           AdsInsights.Field.impressions,
           AdsInsights.Field.clicks,
           AdsInsights.Field.outbound_clicks,
        ]

for account in my_accounts:
    ads = account.get_insights(params=params, fields=fields)
    print(ads)
    print(len(ads))
```

Thanks to @Matteo

Comment: Limit now a days is set to 1000